# How do I search multiple values in coredata model?

Tags: core-data, swift3

I have a students entity with attributes { id: String, name: String, age: Int}

I need to fetch the names and age of multiple ids. Can I do it in single fetch or should fetch for each id separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one fetch. Something like

```
let ids: [String] = // array of ID values
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id in %@", ids)
```

Use that on the fetch request and it will find all entries which have an ID in the array.